# PowerShell - How to get key values of a nested array

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm using the new MS Graph PowerShell cmds, and trying to get a list of all the users assigned as owners of an Azure AD application registration using the cmd `Get-MgApplicationOwner`

```
Get-MgApplicationOwner -ApplicationId $appObjectId
```

This gives me the results as below, with 2 user owners

| Id | DeletedDateTime | AdditionalProperties |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | -- | {[@odata.type, #microsoft.graph.user], [businessPhones, System.Object[]], [displayName, User1 LastName], [givenName, User1]...} |
| 00000000-0000-0000-1111-000000000000 | -- | {[@odata.type, #microsoft.graph.user], [businessPhones, System.Object[]], [displayName, User2], [userPrincipalName, User2@domain.com]} |

If I do `(Get-MgApplicationOwner -ApplicationId $appObjectId).AdditionalProperties`, I can see all the properties of the 2 users as 1 table

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| @odata,type | "#microsoft,graph,user" |
| businessPhones | {1234567890} |
| displayName | User1 LastName |
| givenName | User1 |
| mail | User1@domain.com |
| surname | LastName |
| userPrincipalName | User1@domain.com |
| @odata,type | #microsoft,graph,user |
| businessPhones | {} |
| displayName | User2 |
| userPrincipalName | User2@domain.com |

I'm trying to get the `UserPrincipalNames` from this `AdditionalProperties` array, and
I've tried dot-notation `(Get-MgApplicationOwner -ApplicationId $appObjectId).AdditionalProperties.UserPrincipalName` but no luck. I know I could do a lookup against each Id but would prefer not to

Desired output as an array

```
User1@domain.com    
User2@domain.com
```

Comment: Seems to be a hashtable so you should treat it as such. What does  `(Get-MgApplicationOwner -ApplicationId $appObjectId).AdditionalProperties | gm` output for the type?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala `gm` outputs as `TypeName: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=redacted],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=redacted]]`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon This gave the same results as dot-notation (nothing when using `.AdditionalProperties.UserPrincipalName`, and the table above using just `.AdditionalProperties`)

Comment: yes `system.collections.generic.dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is case sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the answer is that the key value was case-sensitive. Both dot-notation and SantiagoSquarzon's solution work when using case-correct `userPrincipalName`